# Can I craft a link that sets up "Alert Me" options?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, list-view, alert

I know how to create a link to the "Alert Me" feature of a library (opens dialog box just like if the user clicked "Set alert on this library" in the Library tab of the Ribbon. Is there a way to craft that link to change some of the default options? Specifically I'd like the alert to trigger on "Someone changes an item that appears in the following view:" with a specific view selected. It would also be nice to customize the Alert Title and perhaps specify the Change Type.

My environment is currently using SharePoint 2013. I do not have access to SharePoint Designer. I have site owner permissions for the sub-site hosting the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default,  if you have custom views which filter items based on Choice column, you could set alerts on these views. So you can have a try.

About customizing alert template, if you just have site owner permissions, you can't do that because alert template file is in 15 hive folder on your SharePoint server, you need to have farm account to access it.

Some blogs for your reference:
[Create alerts on views in SharePoint document library](http://sharepointviews.com/create-alerts-views-sharepoint-document-library/)
[How to Cusomize Alert Email for SharePoint 2013](http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-cusomize-alert-email-for.html)

Comment: Yes, I know that I can make a filtered view and set an alert based on that view. I'm trying to make an easy way to allow other users to subscribe to that alert based on the custom view. While I would also like to customize the alert template, I know that that is beyond my access level.